# Monitors not being recognized 23.04 Thunderbolt 4 Dock NVIDIA 525

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, thunderbolt, 23.04

**Problem**

Upgraded from 20.04 LTS to 23.04 now:
The main monitor on the laptop does not work.
Only one monitor of three works on Thunderbolt 4 dock. I am using two DisplayPort and one HDMI on the dock, all terminating into HDMI on the monitors.
I can get one additional monitor to work if I use the HDMI port on the laptop.

I was using the NVIDIA 530 drivers before but for some reason, 23.04 does not have them, so now using 525.

**Goal**

Get all three external monitors to work. Also, having a laptop screen would be nice.

**Hardware involved.**

Lenovo P15 Workstation A2000

https://ubuntu.com/certified/202108-29350

https://psref.lenovo.com/syspool/Sys/PDF/ThinkPad/ThinkPad_P15_Gen_2/ThinkPad_P15_Gen_2_Spec.pdf

Three Dell P2721Q 4k monitors.

https://www.dell.com/ae/business/p/dell-p2721q-monitor/pd

ThinkPad Thunderbolt 4 Workstation Dock - US (newest firmware)

https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/p/accessories-and-software/docking/docking_thunderbolt-docks-(universal-cable-docks)/40b00300us

Cables

[https://www.amazon.com/dp/B08FBGNR8C?ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_product_details&th=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08FBGNR8C)
[https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07WNM2NJ5?psc=1&ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_product_details](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07WNM2NJ5)

**System info**

```
$ uname -r
6.2.0-20-generic
```

```
#sudo nvidia-smi
Fri May 12 20:21:10 2023       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 525.105.17   Driver Version: 525.105.17   CUDA Version: 12.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA RTX A200...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| N/A   49C    P8    10W /  60W |   1610MiB /  4096MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      2977      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                748MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      3358      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell              118MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      3376      G   ...libexec/mutter-x11-frames       35MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      5185      G   ...271467521750677320,262144      561MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

```
#xrandr --query
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 7680 x 2160, maximum 32767 x 32767
DP-4.1.6 connected primary 3840x2160+3840+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 597mm x 336mm
   3840x2160     60.00*+  60.00    59.94    50.00    29.97    25.00    23.98  
   2560x1440     59.95  
   2048x1280     59.92  
   1920x1080     60.00    59.94    50.00    29.97    25.00    23.98  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x720      59.94    50.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    59.94    59.93  
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 connected 3840x2160+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 597mm x 336mm
   3840x2160     60.00*+  60.00    59.94    50.00    29.97    25.00    23.98  
   2560x1440     59.95  
   2048x1280     59.92  
   1920x1080     60.00    59.94    50.00    29.97    25.00    23.98  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x720      59.94    50.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    59.94    59.93  
DP-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-5 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

```
#xrandr --listproviders
Providers: number : 1
Provider 0: id: 0x217 cap: 0x1, Source Output crtcs: 4 outputs: 8 associated providers: 0 name:NVIDIA-0
```

```
$ sudo dmesg|grep nvidia
[    4.160298] nvidia: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[    4.160305] nvidia: module license 'NVIDIA' taints kernel.
[    4.174545] nvidia: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[    4.242337] nvidia-nvlink: Nvlink Core is being initialized, major device number 509
[    4.242837] nvidia 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0003)
[    4.243044] nvidia 0000:01:00.0: vgaarb: changed VGA decodes: olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=none:owns=none
[    4.299669] nvidia-modeset: Loading NVIDIA Kernel Mode Setting Driver for UNIX platforms  525.105.17  Tue Mar 28 22:18:37 UTC 2023
[    4.304755] [drm] [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Loading driver
[    7.035908] audit: type=1400 audit(1683915797.311:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="nvidia_modprobe" pid=782 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    7.035912] audit: type=1400 audit(1683915797.311:7): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="nvidia_modprobe//kmod" pid=782 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    7.343491] [drm] Initialized nvidia-drm 0.0.0 20160202 for 0000:01:00.0 on minor 1
[    7.358384] nvidia_uvm: module uses symbols nvUvmInterfaceDisableAccessCntr from proprietary module nvidia, inheriting taint.
[    7.380408] nvidia-uvm: Loaded the UVM driver, major device number 507.
[   41.338234] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   41.338427] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   41.338550] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   41.338656] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   41.391042] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   41.391268] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   41.391393] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   41.391503] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   41.443284] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   41.443505] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   41.443640] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   41.443763] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[20597.967084] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[20597.967185] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[20597.967235] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[20597.967283] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
```